# for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $x=y+2n$ for some $y\in [0,2)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the interval $[0,2)$. Also, we know that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}[2n,2(n+1))$. Now what I need to prove is that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $x=y+2n$ for some $y\in [0,2)$ . Looks simple enough but just cannot see a way to prove this. Hope someone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: Hint: for any real x there is a natural number n such that x=n+y and y is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that  $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}[2n,2(n+1))$ let $x \in 
\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then there exists some integer $m$ such that $x \in [2m,2(m+1)).$

So we have the following inequalies $$2m\leq x\leq2(m+1)\implies0\leq x-2m<2$$

So $x-2m \in[0,2)$. Done!